# Bootstrap vertical align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of images in my bootstrap application.

I am trying to get them vertically aligned, like this:

[image]

This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/9v97xsp9/

And the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/400/" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: eh where is your code?

Comment: Did you try CSS vertical-align ?

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/ not especially for bootstrap, but a starting point

Comment: @23tux I already tried that, and did not success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your row a class `.imageRow` so that you don't affect other `col-md-2` classes.

```
<div class="row imageRow">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/400/" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS:

```
.imageRow {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.imageRow .col-md-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .imageRow .col-md-2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9v97xsp9/2/

Explanation:

Bootstrap uses `float` for their layout. Which IMO is a really lousy way to do things because it was not meant for positioning containers but rather allow text-wrapping around images or containers.

In using `float`, the elements effectively no longer "occupy space". Hence, we need to remove it.

Additionally, in order for sibling elements to vertical align themselves, they need to be `inline` elements. In this case, `inline-block` is the ideal property to use.

`inline` elements have natural whitespaces. So the workaround is to take out the font and line-height.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write a thorough answer. However, it doesn't seem to work at the first breakpoint (http://jsfiddle.net/9v97xsp9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/9v97xsp9/1/

```
.va{
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

for the container divs.